# libncurses.so.5 can not be finded install swift programming language

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to install swift to Debian 9, I download the package from swift.org. I find that there doesn't provide a Debian version, so I just download a ubuntu version, but I find I can run swift --version to show the version of swift, but I can't run REPL successfully, shows that:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I try to fix this problem fellow the Internet, I install something like lib32z1,libncurses5:i386,lib32ncurses5, but none of them fix this problem, so how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I have libncurses.so.6 installed. I solved the problem by copying three .so files from an older install. I had .5.9 versions. I then symlinked those to .5 versions. These were the three libraries that I had to add before swift would run:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 ->
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libform.so.5 ->
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libform.so.5.9

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpanel.so.5 ->
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpanel.so.5.9
```

I copied the 5.9 versions, then I symlinked the .5 versions to the 5.9 versions.